# error: 'enumElement' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, enums

I wrote the following little script:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    enum class Day {sunday, monday, thuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday};
    Day unusedDay, today = sunday;
}
```

But i have a problem. When I debug the programm, the compiler says:

```
error: 'sunday' was not declared in this scope
```

but there is my enum class. Why sunday isn't declared? How can I change that?

Thanks for answears:)

Comment: `sunday` not being accessible like that is half of the point of using `enum class` in the first place.

Comment: See [scoped enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: @mep, if you found any of the answers correct, please mark them so by clicking the grey checkmark icon next to the answer, under the downvote arrow, and it should turn green for an answer to be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing an `enum` with an `enum class`. Suppose your code was this:

```
enum Day {sunday, monday, thuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday};
Day unusedDay, today = sunday;
```

Then the above code would compile, since normal `enum`'s have values that are visible globally, so you can access them like `Day unusedDay, today = sunday;`. As for `enum class`es, the rules differ a little. For your example to work, you would to write the code like this:

```
enum Day {sunday, monday, thuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday};
Day unusedDay, today = Day::sunday;
```

If you look at the documentation for `enum`'s vs `enum class`es, you see this:

**Enum**

> Declares an **unscoped** enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed -

Note the use of the word **unscoped** here meaning the variable is available just with it's name.

**Enum Class**

> declares a **scoped** enumeration type whose underlying type is int (the keywords class and struct are exactly equivalent)

As seen here, an `enum class` is scoped, and accessibly only as `enumname::value`;

([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum))

Answer (score 7):

Write

```
Day unusedDay, today = Day::sunday;
```

The enumerators are in the scope of the enumeration.